# problem on making .csv of contact list:android

Tags: android

I want to make .csv file of "contact name" and corresponding "contact no."  but when i run the code following below given error occurs pls. see my code below and suggest me where i am wrong .
means i have two columns one is name and second is contact no and values should be showh below that coloumn.so pls see my code .**i am new in android and java**.

```
public class contactlist extends Activity {
    static String name;
    static int count;
    static int countno;
    File file = null ;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cur.moveToNext())
            {

                            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            //error on below line
                            String phoneno = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            cur.close();

                            String columnString =   "\"PersonName\",\"phoneno\"";

                            String dataString = null;

                            dataString = "\"" + name +"\",\"" + phoneno + "\"";    
                            Log.i("saurabh",dataString);

                            String combinedString = columnString + "\n" + dataString;

                            File root   = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            if (root.canWrite()) {
                                    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/PersonData");
                                    dir.mkdirs();
                                    file = new File(dir, "Data.csv");
                                    FileOutputStream out = null;

                                    try {
                                            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                            out.write(combinedString.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                            out.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }

                    }
            }
    }
}
```

error is....

```
 07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
  07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
  07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
   07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
        07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
         07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at contactlist.pkg.contactlist.onCreate(contactlist.java:83)
        07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     07-28 16:09:56.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable, please properly format it!

Comment: I did it for him. Also @ram ji, you don't have to use multiple try...catch blocks.

Comment: sir can you give me idea about how to make csv file of contact information.so that inconsistensy not occurs means if i save name in one array and contactno in one other array and if any contact details  not have contactno but only have contact name then inconsistency should be ..so pls help me sir...

Comment: @Ragunath Jawahar  hi ..if you have any other idea for do that  then pls pls can you share me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) library, it can both read and write CSVs. The rest of the logic goes into your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ContactlistActivity extends Activity {

    String name;
    File file = null;

    String[] names = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Application");
            boolean var = false;
            if (!folder.exists())
                var = folder.mkdir();

            System.out.println("" + var);

            String filename = folder.toString() + "/Contact.csv";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

            fw.append("Name");
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append("Number");
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append('\n');

            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,names,null,null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+ " ASC");
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneno = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String dataString = null;
                    dataString = "\"" + name + "\",\"" + phoneno + "\"";

                    fw.append("" + name);
                    fw.append(',');
                    fw.append("" + phoneno);
                    fw.append(',');
                    fw.append('\n');        
                }
                cur.close();
                fw.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One note: if cursor is empty (`getCount() == 0`), fileWriter `fw` will  not be closed.